# How can I get reputation fast?

Tags: support

I need 75 reputation for bounties, but the speed is so slow!

Is there a way to get reputation a little bit faster?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/310045

Comment: Simple: put in effort. That's all it takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Robotnik's answer, I'll add ways to **avoid losing** reputation.

- Don't post rants as questions.  Recently, [you've done just this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306405/i-am-quitting-arquade-due-to-too-much-hate).  Posts like this are always down voted.
- When posting a question or answer, try to make it as grammatically correct as possible, and try to not make any typos.  Small typos and grammar errors people usually don't mind, but if a post is incomprehensible, it is usually down voted.  You can always edit your own posts.
- Ranting in comments is nearly just as bad as a rant post.  Although a comment doesn't impact your reputation total, it does impact your reputation as a user of the site.  Other users **will** keep that in mind.
- Research your question prior to posting it.  Asking a trivial question often results in bad feedback since they aren't very helpful to the community.
- When providing answers, try to draw from credible sources.  When drawing from credible sources, provide a link and an explanation that summarizes the link appropriately.
- [Always stay on topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

As [Frank said](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/how-can-i-get-reputation-fast#comment38627_12345) in the comments:

> Simple: put in effort. That's all it takes.

Those are words to live by here on Arqade.  You ought to listen to your elders ;)

Answer (score 9):

Reputation is *earned*, not given. From the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help):

> ### What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?
>
> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about. Basic use of the site, including asking questions, answering, and suggesting edits, does not require any reputation at all. But the more reputation you earn, the more privileges you gain.
>
> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting **good questions** and **useful answers**. Votes on these posts cause you to gain (or sometimes lose) reputation. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation.
> <sub>[Help Center > Reputation & Moderation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)</sub>

Instead of focusing on 'getting reputation faster', have a read of what makes a [Good Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Good Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), and have a look at improving your current questions and answers if you can.

Having a larger backlog of (high quality!) questions and answers will also help to increase your reputation. If you see a question that you know the answer to that hasn't been answered with the solution you were going to provide, answer it!

Keep in mind that questions you ask should reflect actual issues/problems that you've faced. Show your testing & research and be ready to edit/update your question to respond to comments. If you manage to find a solution to your problem, you can answer your own question with the solution as well, it's not only allowed, but encouraged!

In conclusion:

> *"Worry more about your character than your reputation. Character is what you are, reputation merely what others think you are."*
> <sub>― John Wooden</sub>

Don't look for 'quick and dirty' ways to increase reputation. Show us that you can be a valuable member of the community, write high-quality questions and answers that showcase who you are and what you're good at, and these contributions will translate into more reputation naturally.

Comment: Note that the minimum amount for placing a bounty is 50 of **your reputation**.  That means, at 75 reputation, you'll go back down to 25, and lose any privileges in between. In this case, that would just be the ability to comment anywhere, but if you lose enough reputation to go below a privilege minimum, you'll lose that privilege as well.