# 200 daily Max Reputation Tips

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

According to the [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) section on the help center, you can earn 200 max. There are Bronze, Silver, and Gold badges with their description being that you should collect 200 max reputation.

- [Mortarboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard)
- [Epic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/145/epic)
- [Legendary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/146/legendary)

---

I would like to earn 200 max reputation, but I find it difficult. Is there any tips?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/how-can-i-get-reputation-fast

These are some of the hardest badges to get on this SE site, or really *any* SE site.  On this site, only 6 people have the [Epic badge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/145/epic), and [two Legendary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/146/legendary), and the site has been around for almost 11 years at this point.

Comment: just don't [game the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again). relax, sit back and answer whatever you truly can with good quality.

Answer (score 5):

Post well thought out and written questions and answers, especially on currently popular games, and the rep will follow!

Comment: Editing tag wikis is also a reliable option

Comment: @Batophobia I wouldn’t say editing tag wikis is reliable when trying to reach the 200 daily max. Edits could sit in the queue days before being processed

Comment: Oh I get it, this is an April Fools answer!

Comment: Your advice is very useful, but what about [this question?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383470/why-isnt-motion-controls-working-in-fortnite-battle-royale) What details else is desired for at least 10 upvotes on it?

Comment: @loan_2314 Editing it periodically to post updates on a question you're really invested into will bump it on the front page and attract votes. That said, editing for the sake of bumping is frowned upon.

Comment: Can you split that into pieces, please (break it down) @ExpertCoder14

Comment: @loan_2314 Break down what?

Comment: Your comment. @ExpertCoder14